# How to answer an academic job interview question about how I will contribute to growth and sustainability of school / academic unit?

Tags: job-search, interview

I am going to attend an academic job interview. In the email arranging the appointment, the university asked me to prepare a 10-minute presentation outlining how I will contribute to growth and sustainability of the department in the current higher education environment. How should I approach this?

Comment: What sort of university/college is this? Primarily research? Teaching?

Comment: And, is this your first faculty position or are you moe experienced?

Comment: I am more experienced. This is not my first faculty position.